# $f^*(w \wedge \theta) = (f^*w) \wedge (f^* \theta)$

Tags: differential-topology

I am reading Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology. For the proof on Page 164, I was not able to get through the last step.

> $$f^*(w \wedge \theta) = (f^*w) \wedge (f^* \theta)$$
>
> **Definition.** If $f: X \to Y$ is a smooth map and $\omega$ is a $p$-form on $Y$, define a $p$-form $f^*\omega$ on $X$ as follows: $$f^*\omega(x) = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)].$$

According to Daniel Robert-Nicoud's ansewr to [$f: X \to Y$ is a smooth map and $\omega$ is a $p$-form on $Y$, what is $\omega[f(x)]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455951/f-x-to-y-is-a-smooth-map-and-omega-is-a-p-form-on-y-what-is-omega/455957#455957)

Locally, differential form can be written as
$$\omega_\alpha(y) = \alpha(y)dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_p}$$
with $\alpha$ a smooth function. Then
$$f^*\omega_\alpha(x) = (df_x)^*[(\alpha\circ f)(x)dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_p}].$$

We write
$$\omega_\alpha(y) = \alpha(y)dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_p},$$
$$\theta_\beta(y) = \beta(y)dx^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{j_q}.$$

Hence,
$$\omega \wedge \theta = (\alpha(y)dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_p}) \wedge (\beta(y)dx^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{j_q})$$

Following James S. Cook's very brilliant answer [Pullback expanded form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456086/pullback-expanded-form/456105?noredirect=1#456105)

$$\omega \wedge \theta = \alpha(y) \beta(y) \sigma(I,J) dx^{k_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{k_{p+q}}$$

Rename $\gamma(y) = \alpha(y) \beta(y) \sigma(I,J)$, we get
$$f^*(w \wedge \theta) =  (df_x)^* [(\gamma \circ f)(x) dx^{k_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{k_{p+q}}].$$

But $$(f^*w) \wedge (f^* \theta) = ((df_x)^*[(\alpha\circ f)(x)dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_p}])\wedge((df_x)^*[(\beta\circ f)(x)dx^{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{j_q}])$$

> So here I got stuck - I don't really know how to move around $\alpha, \beta$ under $df^*$, to get close to the left hand side expression.

Thank you!~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your approach but I am giving another approach which might be helpful. Lets start with the definition. If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map and $\omega$ is a $p$ form in $Y$ then its pull back is defined as $f^*(\omega)v=\omega (f_*v).,$ where $f_*v=v(f),$ for any $v\in T_pX.$ Therefore Expand (assuming $\omega$ is a p form and  $\theta$ is a q form) the term (where $v_i$and $w_i$ are in $T_pX$ ) $f^*(\omega\wedge \theta)(v_1,\cdots ,v_p,w_1,\cdots ,w_q)=(\omega\wedge \theta)(f_*(v_1),\cdots ,f_*(v_p),f_*(w_1),\cdots ,f_*(w_q)).$ using the summation formula for wedge product. Which will be same as $\omega(f_∗(v_1),⋯,f_∗(v_p))\wedge \theta(f_*(w_1),⋯,f_∗(w_q)).$ Which is (by definition) same as $f^*(\omega)\wedge f^*(\theta).$

Comment: looks great, thanks tessellation. I wonder if my approach is wrong.

Comment: @WishingFish notice he is doing what I said in the other thread. That is what the $df_x^*$ intends. It might be good to look back at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455233/fw-wedge-theta-fw-wedge-f-theta/455250#455250 or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451246/pullback-of-a-1-form/451436#451436 where I focus more on the issue of how the pull-back replaces the coefficient with the composition of the old coefficient.

Comment: It feels like physicists and geometers haven't met an agreement on many mathematical expressions yet, but I am really confused and frustrated by the different notation from the one I am introduced. Because I am constrained in the idea that if I want to use another definition, I shall prove its equivalence first... @JamesS.Cook

Comment: To be more specific, I am confused with tessellation's definition $f^*(\omega)v = \omega(f_*v)$ with my $f^*(\omega)v = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)]$, @JamesS.Cook

Comment: This answer may be misleading...see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608269/pullback-distributes-over-wedge-product?noredirect=1#comment1281135_608269

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$f^*(w \wedge \theta) = (df_x)^*(\omega\wedge\theta)[f(x)].$$

> Page 162: If $\omega$ is a $p$-form and $\theta$ is a $q$-form, then $p+q$ form
>   $$(\omega \wedge \theta) (x) = \omega(x) \wedge \theta(x).$$

Therefore,
$$(df_x)^*(\omega\wedge\theta)[f(x)] = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)] \wedge \theta[f(x)].$$

> Page 159: $A^*$ is linear and that
>   $$A^*(T \wedge S) = A^*T \wedge A^*S.$$

Therefore,
$$(df_x)^*\omega[f(x)] \wedge \theta[f(x)] = (df_x)^*\omega[f(x)] \wedge (df_x)^*\theta[f(x)].$$

That is exactly
$$(f^*w) \wedge (f^* \theta).$$